# Get Text from ~(';')+ in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Using Antlr-grammar for parsing a SQL File, I wanna get the total text value of `~(';')+` in order to log this information I did not parse deeply. Unfortunately, calling getText() on that results only in the last word.

This is the active parsing rule:

```
...
constraintName=alter_table_constraint_name 'CHECK' content=~(';')+  #alterTableAddCheck
...
```

which parses this part fine:

```
ALTER TABLE "UFHDBTBL"."FH01T54" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FH01C54_DYNAMIC" CHECK 
        (DYNAMIC IN ('Y','N'))
    ENFORCED
    ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;
```

Calling getText() in my program later results in the output of "OPTIMIZATION" only. Anyone an idea, how to get the whole block?

Comment: You cannot use `~(';')+` in a parser rule but only in a lexer rule. Although if you put it in a lexer rule this will probably not do what you want... . Can you post your complete grammar?

Comment: I don't think posting the whole grammar is really necessary (it has ~500 lines and works fine). Just tried putting the `~(';')+` in a new parser rule and linking the `content=new_rule` to it. Works fine!

Comment: Ok. I verified that `~(';')+` _is_ valid in a parser rule and seems to match any token except (';').

Comment: The thing is, that I just wanna "ignore" the whole rest of that statement. But for logging purposes it would be nice to access the text of in that case the check constraint. It just seems strange to me, that `content=~(';')*` and `content=new_rule ... new_rule: ~(';')*;` produces 2 different values when calling getText(). Anyways, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found out that `content` is of type `CommonToken`, i.e. `content` only refers to a single token, hence it doesn't contain all tokens.

A fix could be, to promote the label `content` to a `contentRule`:

```
//...
constraintName=alter_table_constraint_name 'CHECK' content=contentRule  #alterTableAddCheck
//...


contentRule : ~(';')+;
```

Or as Sam mentioned [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/682), use this syntax (note the `+=` instead of the `=` after the label name) and get the complete text by concatenating the individual texts of each list member (this even let's you include whitespace between tokens if wished):

```
...
constraintName=alter_table_constraint_name 'CHECK' (content+=~';')+  #alterTableAddCheck
...
```